# Prevent a container to resize because of its children

Tags: wpf, height, border, containers

I have a Border in a grid row (margin="5"). This grid row is supposed to take all available space.

When I execute my program, it works well: I see the border occupying all available space on the window when I manually resize it.

However, if I add a datagrid in the border and this datagrid has many items (thus it has an important height), my border and subsequently my grid row's height adapts.

I've tried to set the datagrid VerticalAlignment to stretch, to no avail.

How can I achieve this please?

Comment: how do you think people are supposed to suggest you without seeing any xaml?

Comment: ASh, by creating a solution from scratch to illustrate my question, I noticed that the behavior described above does not occur. I must find what the problem is another way. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

The problem, in my case, came from a scrollviewer embedding my controls. I removed it --> problem solved.

Thanks to ASh for making me abstract the situation.